# How can I avoid connecting separated parts of a figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have executed the following code to get my figure :

```
plt.figure()    
plt.plot(X, Y, 'r')
plt.ylabel('Ampl')
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.title(My_day.strftime('%d/%m/%Y'))
plt.ylim(0,0.1)
plt.show()
```

I got the next picture, where the content is fine in my pciture: [image]

The problem is that I want to avoid plotting that line between the 2 parts of the figure for example I want to get like this : two separated parts :

[image]

what should I do ?

Comment: Split your data into two parts, then `plot()` each part separately in the same figure.

Comment: What if you instead of `plt.plot` use `plt.xticks`?

Comment: It is not a practical solution because I am plotting within a for loop, I am plotting 32 fgures . So, I will need to split my data to two parts, three or four parts and it is a bit complicated!

Comment: with plt.xticks I got  ''ypeError: Illegal number of arguments to xticks''

Comment: What's the criterion by which you would decide whether a dataset consists of "two parts" or not? If you have such criterion, you can split the data.

Comment: Could you identify these parts and insert `None` in between? Basically just one `None` is needed to make discontinuation between these parts...

Comment: They are random data, in fact they are data collected by a sensor so they are random

Comment: This line is corresponding to a discontinuity  between the data

Comment: You need *a criterion* by which to split. So for example if I have x data like `[1,2,3,6,7,8]` I could use the criterion "difference between successive data larger than 1" to split the data in two.

Comment: If it is random data, and you do not have a criterion to split the data, do not plot your data in a line plot, only use markers. E.g try `plt.plot(X, Y, 'r.')` Note, the `.` (dot). The line will dissapear but your single data points won't be connected anymore, though

Comment: As it is clear in my Picture the x axis is the time could this help me?

Comment: But I really want to connect the rest is there any solution please?

Comment: I wonder why people are suggesting me to improve this question by writting For example and not for example etc.. I asked this question because I am really searching for a solution to my problem of avoiding plotting discontinuity so please stop trying only to catch points